# Como funcionam as entradas da função main em C?

Tags: c, funções

Eu sempre usei a função main da seguinte forma, criando outras funções:

```
int main() {
    .
    .
    .
    return 0;
}
```

Como funcionam as entradas na função main?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
```

Temos uma variável e um char, não é? Assim, tenho que fornecer estes valores antes de executar o programa, correto?

Poderia, em shell, executar a seguinte linha, por exemplo:

```
./bin/programa -e ./data/entrada.txt  -s ./data/saida.net
```

Correto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você tem um array de strings (char **argv) de tamanho inteiro (int argc). É importante observar que o parâmetro da posição 0 é o nome do próprio programa, e os próximos são os parâmetros passados na linha de comando assim o seu exemplo nos daria o seguinte:

```
argv[0] = "./bin/programa"
argv[1] = "-e"
argv[2] = "./data/entrada.txt"
argv[3] = "-s"
argv[4] = "./data/saida.net"
```

Comment: @GuilhermeBrügger Está certo, eu coloquei que era inteiro mas não expliquei o que ele era! Valeu!

Comment: Entendi! E os valores (int para argc e os char para argv) ficam salvos nestas "variáveis"? Posso utilizá-los na função, correto?

Comment: @Klel pode usar sim. Se você achar que a resposta ajudou pode aceitá-la como solução. Isso ajuda às pessoas que respondem :)